# Difference between S-R flip flop and D flip flop

Tags: flipflop

What is the difference between a D flip flop and an SR flip flop?

Comment: Sounds *very* home-workish...

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the flip flops, pretty new to this.

Comment: Neither one has an inherent problem. They do two different things.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Well.. one of the input combinations of SR is problematic.. But that's what JK is solving.

Comment: OK, after the edit the question is becoming off-topic (or too broad? VTC, anyway.). This information is easily available around and you have to do your own research... Oh wait.. @laptop2d it was *your* edit. I think it's quite different from the OPs intent.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I suppose if you don't use it as intended- though D FF has similar issues if you ignore hold and setup times.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah, but one might say that this specific problem is inherent to SR but solved in D.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're cleverly thinking like a student which will get the right answer and the mark, but I can't see dropping one in, in place of the other so the question is a bit suspect in my opinion.

Comment: The intent was listed in the title, I thought it needed to be a bit more readable, feel free to roll back the changes if they are too much. Edits have an approval process

Comment: D-Type is synchronous logic. S-R is asynchronous.

Comment: @trevor You can have synchronous S-R flops most of the time they are async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A D-flip flop** basically stores the value for one clock cycle (and functions as a buffer, a chip enable pin will let you store for multiple clock cycles).

*Table 1. The truth table for D flip-flop*

```
+---+---+------------+-------------+
| c | D | Output     | Function    |
+---+---+------------+-------------+
|   | x | No change  | Store       |
+---+---+------------+-------------+
| ↑ | 1 | 1          | Transparent |
+---+---+------------+-------------+
| ↑ | 0 | 0          | Transparent |
+---+---+------------+-------------+
```

**An SR flip flop** is like a light switch. `Set` turns it 'on' and `reset` turns it 'off'

Table 2. The truth table for SR flip-flop

```
+-----+---+---+------------+-----------+
| clk | S | R | Output     | Function  |
+-----+---+---+------------+-----------+
|     | x | x | no change  | Store     |
+-----+---+---+------------+-----------+
| ↑   | 0 | 0 | no change  | Store     |
+-----+---+---+------------+-----------+
| ↑   | 1 | 0 | 1          | Set       |
+-----+---+---+------------+-----------+
| ↑   | 0 | 1 | 0          | Reset     |
+-----+---+---+------------+-----------+
| ↑   | 1 | 1 | ?          | Undefined |
+-----+---+---+------------+-----------+
```